# How to remove the underline from URLs in a CDATA tag?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, cdata

I am trying to remove the underline from URLs in my android app but I am not able to do it. I have in my strings.xml a string with normal text and inside, a CDATA tag with a URL using the HTML `<a>` tag. In my code, I apply this string as HTML using `Html.fromHtml`. Is it possible to remove this underline from URLs? I would also like that in addition to removing this underline, the URL was in bold but this is secondary.

Comment: I assume that the fact that the URL is underlined is due to the styles that are being applied to the `<a>` tag.  To get rid of the underline, you would therefore change some bit of CSS or otherwise cause the styling applied to the tag to change. - Without more information, I don't think anyone can tell you just where to make such a change. - Also, CDATA has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: @CryptoFool How can I apply CSS? I tried to apply CSS inline using text-decoration:none but it does not apply.

Comment: Not being able to see your code, I don't know what to tell you.